# How to redraw the drawing in canvas when orientation changed

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

My code is working fine not until the table or the device is rotated. When rotated the drawing got cleared and I learned it happen because when the device gets rotated, the activity is restarted.
My problem is how redraw and save the data to onSaveInstanceState.
Many said that I have to use onSaveInstanceState to save the drawing, but i don't know how to do it when the datatype I have to save is the Path.

here is the snippet of my code

```
public class MyDrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    MyDrawView drawView;
    float prevX = 0;
    float prevY = 0;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int w,h;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Paint> bitPaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    private ArrayList<Paint> pathPaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    Paint tempPaint;
    private String filename="";

    public MyDrawView(Context c,String filename) {
        super(c);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);


        this.filename=filename;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        tempPaint=new Paint(mPaint);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();
        if (rotated){
            setDefaultDrawing();
        }

    }
    public void setDefaultDrawing()
    {

    }
    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
        return this.mBitmap;
    }
    public void setStrokeWidth(float width){
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    }
    public void setColor(int color){
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }
    public String getFileName(){
        return this.filename;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        this.w=w;
        this.h=h;
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        Path tempPath=new Path(mPath);
        paths.add(tempPath);
        Paint tempPaint=new Paint(mPaint);
        pathPaints.add(tempPaint);
        Paint tempBitPaint=new Paint(mBitmapPaint);
        bitPaints.add(tempBitPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
```

Comment: better fix the orientation in the manifest...use either portrait for land scape

Comment: I wish i can just do that ease to my burden but i have to make it flexible :( have to make it work both in portrait and landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, since Path is a custom object, I created a class object that will hold the Path, in that way, I can just save the class object in my onSaveInstanceState and retrieve it using the same class object.

Comment: please elaborate if you still remember this.

Comment: if you have solution, you should provide more detail to help others.  You could not have just created an object without making that object Parcelable.  That is useful information to others

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbles across this. You need to create a class that contains Path and the path needs to implement Parcelable.

e.g

```
public static class CustomPath extends Path implements Parcelable {

    private Path path;

    public CustomPath() {

    }

    protected CustomPath(Parcel in) {
        path = (Path) in.readValue(Path.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(path);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public final Parcelable.Creator<CustomPath> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CustomPath>() {
        @Override
        public CustomPath createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CustomPath(in);
        }

        @Override
        public CustomPath[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CustomPath[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Once you've done that you need to save the CustomPath in the Activity Method `onSaveInstanceState()`

Example

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelable("_Canvas", _DrawingView.getPath());
}
```

And thento restore the previous Canvas in your `onViewStateRestored()`

Example:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);         
       _DrawingView.setPath(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("_Canvas"));
    }
```

Obviously checking if the key exists and that the Bundle is not null.

**Bonus** to resize the Paths if your Canvas is changing size. Add the following code

```
                    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
                    RectF rectF = new RectF();
                    path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
                    scaleMatrix.setScale(1.25f, 1.25f,rectF.centerX(),rectF.centerY());
                    path.transform(scaleMatrix);
```